# Typescript casting to number worked but now is not

Tags: angular, typescript

Yesterday i was casting some strings to number and they were working, now they don't ( i even did a commit thinking that everything was ok) , i tried to cast in any other ways, but still get Nan, it looks like something is happening to the variable that i assign the values that i cast(because i print them in console.log, and they are being casted)... so what am i doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
  totalPrice: number;
  total: number;


if (this.cart_articles) {
            for (let article of this.cart_articles) {
              this.totalPrice += parseFloat(article.price);
              console.log(this.totalPrice); 
      console.log(parseFloat(article.price));


            }
            this.total = this.totalPrice + (this.totalPrice * 0.18);
            this.iva = this.totalPrice * 0.18;
          }
```

So i get Nan on the variables total,totalPrice and iva. But where i use console.log to show the values before assigning them to the variables, they are ok. How can i solve this? Sorry, as you can see, im new at this.

Comment: I guess the problem is with your data, some of the price is either NAN or null, so it becomes as NAN

Comment: You can simply append `|| 0` to `this.totalPrice += parseFloat(article.price)`. However, you should check your data for what get's returned first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize totalPrice with a default value, else it'll just be `undefined`, and `undefined` + any number equals `NaN`.

```
totalPrice= 0;
total = 0;
```

On a side node, you could make it more efficient using `reduce`:

```
if (this.cart_articles) {
    this.totalPrice = this.cart_articles.reduce((totalPrice, article) => totalPrice += parseFloat(article.price), 0);
    this.total = this.totalPrice + (this.totalPrice * 0.18);
    this.iva = this.totalPrice * 0.18;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***Number definition from docs:*** all numbers in TypeScript are floating
>   point values. These floating point numbers get the type number.

You should cast strings to number by using the `unary '+' operator` 
 Plus, if you are using parse function to null it would become NaN, but if you cast with the `'+'` operator it will cast to 0.

```
console.log(parseFloat(null)) // <-- NaN
console.log(+null) // <-- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use Number()

```
let a: string = '0.1';
let b: string = '0.2'
var caclculate: number;

caclculate = Number(a) + Number(b);
console.log(caclculate) // 0.30000000000000004
```